# I will like to go is correct or wrong?

Tags: grammar

I will like to go (home.)" is correct or wrong? Can we use any verb with will like?

Comment: The problem isn't "to go", it's "I will like". Try "I *would* like [something]"

Comment: This isn’t a natural construction, but you can use it to indicate an unnatural situation, e.g. if a person has been hypnotized and his likes and dislikes have been “programmed in”.